# Get value of checkbox of Form1 from Form2 for build Exe

Tags: vb.net

My code is
`If CheckBox4.Checked = True Then
            rtools = True
        Else : rtools = False
        End If`
for Only One Form i now two form My All chekboxs in form2 
every body can help me?

Comment: I seriously don't get what you want. Do u want to create a custom control to have same settings in all your forms or do u want to Control behavior of Form2 from Form1?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in your code for Form2

```
    dim checkboxresults as bool
if form1.checkbox1.checked = true then
checkboxresults = true
else
checkboxresults = false
end if
```